# iOS 14 SKAdNetwork and AppTrackingTransparency implementation

Tags: ios, privacy, ios14, xcode12

Since iOS 14, `AppTrackingTransparency` framework is introduced, i need help in `SKAdNetwork` implementation generating/understanding the extra meta info we need to send in `SKStoreProductViewControler` `loadProductWithParameters:completionBlock:` method. If anybody has a sample code or an E2E overview till complete app installation callback it'll be helpful. Thanks.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/generating_the_signature_to_validate_an_installation

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with the framework?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/singular-labs/Singular-SKAdNetwork-App

Check out this github repository by an MMP partner called Singular - it contains some sample code on how to implement with the transparency framework.

Comment: This is nearly a link-only answer. Could you describe what the code you're pointing to does?